# Excel Nested If formula with Today()

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I have a column named "Status" and is using Nested If formula to derive the appropriate status based on the dates. I have 6 statuses (A7 = Completed, A6 = Review, A5 = Process, A4 = Draft, A3 = In Progress, A2 = Did not start. But if a cell is empty, it will show "Completed" instead of "Did not start". What changes do I need to make for my formula?

```
=
IF(TODAY()>=S3,Sheet2!$A$7,
IF(TODAY()>=Q3,Sheet2!$A$6,
IF(TODAY()>=O3,Sheet2!$A$5,
IF(TODAY()>=M3,Sheet2!$A$4,
IF(TODAY()<K3,Sheet2!$A$2,Sheet2!$A$3
)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

change `... IF(TODAY()<K3....` into `...IF(OR(TODAY()<K3,TODAY()="")...`

Comment: Hi Lambik, it is still showing "Completed" after switching to your answer

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your data?